# Manually allocate number of cores when dynamic allocation is set to true

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

We have a 3 node cluster. Each node has 20 cores and 100GB memory. We have dynamic resource allocation set to true.

I want to tweak the resources as per my wish.

For example:

1. `spark-submit` to use only 1 core. By default it is picking 4-6 cores.
2. I want to set this for every spark-submit I run.

How can I achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is a property of an application. It can be set on each submission, using one of:

- Passing `--conf` option to Spark submit.
- Setting `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` on `SparkConf` object.
- Using `config` method of `SparkSessionBuilder`.